# How are database connections opened by mysql_connect() closed?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

According to the php documention, "The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling mysql_close()."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

When are connections opened and closed for this script for 1) when the username is not posted and 2) when the username is posted (please mind form sanitation)?

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("members") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php
if (isset ($_POST['username'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username) VALUES('$username'") or die (mysql_error());


}
else{
    $username='';
}
?>

<html>
    <form action="register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="username" size="30" maxlength="400" value="<?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($username)); ?>" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: None of the above, `$conn` is a connection as soon as you call `mysql_connect`, and it closes after the _entire_ request has run, _including_ trailing html / non-php output.

Comment: Ah, thank you, newb factor here but I'm learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection is opened at the top of the script, regardless of if the form is posted or not, therefore is opened once on each page load. The connection is closed once the final `</html>` tag is delivered to the client.

Comment: Thank Tak, so if there's no <html></html> and the whole thing is just a php script, it would close once the final </php> tag is delivered to the client, correct?

Comment: Yes it closes at the end of the `.php` file, whether that's PHP or HTML.

Comment: @tak: So, no, not at the final php-tag (`?>`), but at the end of the request. Giving another answer starting with _yes_ is a bit confusing ;)

Comment: One last question, as a corollary let's say I include an mp3 file that's 10mb in the html tag <embed src="song.mp3">.  Would the connection close after the song has been queued, or would it close after the ENTIRE song has loaded?

Comment: Your PHP script only sends the HTML to the client. The client then sends another, separate (usually) request to the server asking for images, CSS, MP3s, etc.

Comment: So is the connection open while the song is loading (which would take a few minutes)?

Comment: _A_ web request connection is, yes, but not the original web request connection, and therefore not the database connection.